# How to get BitmapSource from BitmapImage?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

How to get BitmapSource from BitmapImage? Or how to convert BitmapImage to BitmapFrame directly?
It seems to me that if I have BitmapSource I could use BitmapFrame.Create and finally get BitmapFrame object from given BitmapImage

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between a BitmapFrame and BitmapImage in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155391/difference-between-a-bitmapframe-and-bitmapimage-in-wpf)

Answer (score 12):

A **BitmapImage** inherits from  **BitmapSource** so no conversion is needed

Comment: If I write ImageFrame im = ImageFrame.Create(bitmapImage); this cause error

Comment: Sorry, I have make a mistake. Thank for the answer))

Answer (score 1):

The **BitmapImage** inherits from **BitmapSource** as parapura said.

Example:

```
BitmapSource bitmapSource = new BitmapImage();
BitmapImage bitmapImage = bitmapSource as BitmapImage;
```

Source: [BitmapSource MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#inheritanceContinued)